# getting component is unknown element error although I imported the component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to learn Angular (by creating an application with Ionic), I want to add a custom component that I would create. I used `ng generate` to generate a new component, but when I try to use it, in another component I get an error that says:

```
`'GoalCardComponent' is not a known element:
1. If 'GoalCardComponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.`
```

I tried to search, and saw some threads about this, but nothing worked (I guess maybe things changed in the framework?).

This is GoalCardComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-goal-card',
  templateUrl: './goal-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./goal-card.component.scss'],
})
export class GoalCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

This is the home component:

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {GoalCardComponent} from '../goal-card/goal-card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [
    GoalCardComponent
  ],
})
export class HomePage {
  greetingTitle = "Good morning"
  motivationQuote = "A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step"
  constructor() {}

  createGoal() {
    console.log("Clicked create goal")
  }
}
```

This is the home component html:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-label id="greetingTitle">
      {{greetingTitle}}
    </ion-label>
    <br/>
    <ion-label id="motivationQuote">
      {{motivationQuote}}
    </ion-label>
  </ion-header>

  <app-goal-card>

  </app-goal-card>
  
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed" style="padding: 8pt;">
    <ion-fab-button (click)="createGoal()">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your custom component to the `entryComponents` and `declarations` of your `appModule` :

```
import { GoalCardComponent } from '../goal-card/goal-card.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations:[
    GoalCardComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    GoalCardComponent
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Could you please provide your code on a stackblitz ? https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Thanks, I added the code here (this is really just the start, I didn't change almost anything). Hope that is good enough. Is it possible to import the whole app to stackblitz? because I can't find a way to copy my files to there.

Comment: Here is a stackblitz with a GoalCardComponent : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sb6mj2?file=app/app.module.ts. Once your component created, you need to add it to your `app.module.ts` in the `declarations` and in the `entryComponents` array

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and had the same problem. however, adding the import to home.module.ts worked (while it didn't work before that change), so I guess it is okay now. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share what you provided in the imports of the app.module.ts ? Is your component a modular component ?

Comment: I actually added the same imports you provided, but just added them in the home.module.ts. I did work (I don't get the same error) but now I have another error which I'm trying to solve. but as far as this error go, I think it is solved now.

Comment: Okey nice. Please don't forget to mark answer as resolved if that worked. Have a good day